# Restarting While Loop after false boolean in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, boolean-expression

I'm doing an assignment for school that requires us to find the largest of ten numbers. The numbers are between 0-9. I believe I got that part down. My problem is I'm trying to add an extra feature that is not required for the assignment. I am trying to get the loop to completely restart after the boolean statement is false and gives an error message. After I type the invalid value in, it gives the error message, but after I press "ok" it continues on to the next number. I want it to start back at the beginning of the loop.

Here's the code:

```
package Largest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LargestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 0;
    String numStr = "";
    int []myArray = new int[10];
    int count = 1;
    int largest = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    while(valid == true); {  // Loop to check validity  

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

            myArray[i] = i + 1;
            numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number " + count++ + ":");
            number = Integer.parseInt(numStr); // Converts string value to integer  

            if(number >= largest) {
                largest = number;
            }

            // If-Else if statements checks if values entered are equal to 0-9
            if(number >= 0 && number <= 9) {
                valid = true;
            }

            else if ((!(number >= 0 && number <= 9))) {
                valid = false;
            }   

            if (valid == false) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID INPUT...Try Again!!!", "Results", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
                continue;
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest Number Is: " + largest, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }           
    }
}
```

I could just end the loop here by adding return:

```
if (valid == false) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID INPUT...Try Again!!!", "Results", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    return;
}
```

I just really want to learn how to restart the loop from the beginning. I tried search different topics, but none helped me solve my problem. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The `continue` keyword?

Comment: add another while wrapping your inner while

Comment: @August Post it as an answer. @KinGSwisser `while(valid == true)` can be represented as `while(valid)`. Checking for when the boolean is false would look like: `while(!valid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner and trying to learn, I have done a review of your code and enclosed some comments that might help you. I have posted updated code below.

1. Declarations: You should declare a variable in the innermost closure that requires it. Except `largest`, all other can go inside the `for`.
2. Your array variable did not make sense to have. Since you're keeping track of the largest as you go and not finding it at the end.
3. Control: Your `/loop to check validity/` needs to be strictly around the input part, not your whole program, so you can repeat just the input statements till you're satisfied.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int largest = 0;
       for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       {
           boolean valid = false;      
           while (!valid)
           {
               String numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number " + i + ":");
               int number = Integer.parseInt(numStr);  //Converts string value to integer

               if (number >= 0 && number <= 9)
               {
                   valid = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID INPUT...Try Again!!!", "Results", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
               }           
           }

           if (number > largest)
           {
               largest = number;
           }
       }   
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest Number Is: " + largest, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh cool thanks this helps a lot! I could figure out for the life of me what I was doing wrong. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

To restart a loop, you would use the `continue` keyword. `continue` will skip to the next loop iteration.

When using a while loop, it'll simply restart the loop, since the loop doesn't end til `valid` is true. When using a for loop, itll skip to the next iteration (so if you're currently on index 5 and use continue, it'll move onto index 6 instead of staying at 5).

For nested loops, you can label the loop to specify which loop the statement is for:

```
firstloop:
while(valid) {

    secondloop:
    while(true) {
         continue firstloop;
    }
}
```

Also, no need for `== true` when checking a boolean. It could be represented as

```
while(valid) {

}
```

As for checking for false, `valid == false`, you'd use

```
while(!valid) {

}
```

Comment: @KinGSwisser It's good for any other primitive type like `char` and it's used to check if 2 reference variables point to the same object. The way you're doing it is alright, there's just no need for it

Comment: Labelled loops bear some similarity with branch labels a la 'goto'. Probably a matter of preference but I would not recommend it when you have more elegant ways to design the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a labeled continue:

```
firstloop:
while(valid){
  secondloop:
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++{
    //something
    if(something){
      continue firstloop;
    }
  }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) for more details.

**UPDATE:** Also... there is no need for the condition in the else part of your if/else statement. Just doing a `else{ valid=false }` would be equivalent to what you're doing right now. Another option would be to simplify it even further and skip the if/else part alltogether and just have:

```
valid = number >= 0 && number <= 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function, that is, a function that calls itself.

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
  // optionally ask the user for input at this point before processing begins.

  while(yourCondition)
  {
    // do your stuff.
  }

  // when execution reaches here the condition is no longer valid; start over.
  if(conditionToStartOver)
      DoSomething();  // start again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is almost right but you shouldn't be looping on `valid` in the outer loop. Remember, you want to stop the *inner* loop when an input is invalid. Normally the outer loop would give the user an option to exit the program.

So for example:

```
while(true) {
    boolean valid = true;

    for(...; ...; ...) {
        ...

        if(number < 0 || 9 < number) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valid) {
        // show largest input dialog
    } else {
        // show invalid input dialog
    }

    // optionally ask the user if they want to exit
    // if so, break
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Radiodef and everyone this one really helpful community. I just hope to get to all you guys level of knowledge in programming. I just finished C++ and sql database programming classes. Although I love C++. I am really loving Java so far and hope to get better at it. I really do appreciate you guys though!